# Ways to solve compounding interest questions?

Tags: logarithms, finance

Ed invests $\$15,000$ into an account that pays an annual rate of $3.5\%$ interest compounded k times per year where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. At the end of two years the investment is worth $\$16,087$. Find the smallest value of $k$.

For this question, I solved it using my TI-84's graphing calculator, and got $k=32$ by finding the intersection.
My two equations are:
$$ 
Y_1 = 16087\\
Y_2 = 15000(1+\dfrac{3.5}{100x})^{2x}
$$

However, there is also a "TVM solver" function on the calculator, and I am wondering if there is a way to rearrange my equation to solve for $x$ using the TVM solver. I attempted to solve it by  setting:
$$
N=2\\
I=3.5\\
PV=15000\\
FV=-16087\\
P/Y=1\\
C/Y= \text{to solve}\\
$$

This gave me $k=1$, which results in the compounding interest to become $\$16068.38$ - which is incorrect.
Any other methods to solve these kinds of questions - that is, where the x is in the denominator and the exponent - would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can solve this with a TVM calculator, but we can solve this iteratively. We have
$$
f(x) = 15~000~\left(1 + \frac{3.5}{100x} \right)^{2x} - 16~087
$$
from which we are trying to find the root. We can use Newton's method, for example. The derivative is
$$
f'(x)=30~000~\left(1+\frac{3.5}{100x}\right)^{2x} \cdot \frac{ (0.035 + x) \ln \left(\frac{0.035 + x}{x} \right) -0.035}{0.035 + x}
$$

With a starting guess $x_0$, we can start iterating so that
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}
$$
Let's start from $x_0=1$. Then we get the following table (rounding $x$ to integer values):

\begin{array}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline 
x_n & f(x_n) & f'(x_n)  & x_{n+1} & \text{rounded} \\
 \hline
1    & -18.625    & 18.800 & 1.991 & 2 \\
2    & -9.115     & 4.811  & 3.894 & 4 \\
4    & -4.275     & 1.217  & 7.512 & 8 \\
8    & -1.833     & 0.306  & 13.990 & 14 \\
14   & -0.783     & 0.100  & 21.809 & 22 \\
22   & -0.272     & 0.041  & 28.697 & 29 \\
29   & -0.056     & 0.023  & 31.406 & 31 \\
31   & -0.013     & 0.020  & 31.611 & 32 \\
32   & 0.007      & 0.019  & 31.619 & 32\\
 \hline  
\end{array}

The iteration has converged to $x=32$.

Answer (score 0):

The result is quite close to $1$ but the equation cannot be solved even using special function.

If you make a series expansion
$$0=-\frac{149}{8}+\frac{621}{4}  \left(7+207 \log
   \left(\frac{207}{200}\right)\right)(x-1)+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$
$$x\sim 1+\frac{149}{1242 \left(7+207 \log
   \left(\frac{207}{200}\right)\right)}=1.00850$$ while the "exact" solution is $1.00846$.

Using the approximate gives for $\text{(rhs-lhs)}$ a value of $0.087988$ instead of $-18.6250$ if $x=1$.